# how to solve system of ODE over finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, algorithms, sagemath, macaulay2

I would be very grateful if someone can help me to solve this problem . I have to find seven polynomials lets call them $ a(t),b(t)... $ in $\mathbb{F}_{2}[t]$ that solves a system of 6 equations of the type :$a(t)+b(t)c(t)+c_{t}(t)=0$ where $f_{t}(t)$ denotes the derivative.Can i have any hints on how i can implement an algorithm that can solve this kind of problems. I am thinking about using Sage or Macaulay2 but i dont know how i can write the algorithm .
Thank you very much

Comment: What are the 6 equations exactly? You could introduce undetermined coefficients for each of your polynomials; each polynomial equation in $t$ then becomes a system of equations (one equation for each power of $t$ that appears).